# Deserialize unknown Json-type Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I had a json-structure with unkown keys.
Here is a random example:

```
{
    "menu": {
        "header": "xProgress SVG Viewer",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "Open"
            },
            {
                "id": "OpenNew",
                "label": "Open New"
            }
}
```

Now I want to read all data and do some action for each value.
I found 2 methods, but both not easy to handle:

```
object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Count() == 0)
        //Access with 'prop.Name' and 'prop.GetValue(obj, null)'
        //But Iam not able to handle this correctly
```

and

```
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(data)))
    while (reader.Read())
        //Access with 'reader.Value'
        //Complex - next picture
```

`string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", reader.TokenType, reader.ValueType, reader.Value)`
[image: because data looks like]

Its to complex to work on this data (arrays are also possible). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `dynamic` object?

Comment: Third approach is `dynamic` - [dynamic (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: But I dont know the keys. And I try to avoid dynamic (bad performance).

Comment: Then use JObject. It is in the docs

Comment: Have you noticed performance issues when you have used `dynamic` in your case? `dynamic` using reflection (as your second approach). but with benefit of caching

Comment: `dynamic` uses reflection under the hood to access methods and properties. It isn't going to be any worse performance than your first option of using reflection directly.

Comment: @Abion47- it can be even better in some cases, because `dynamic` will not use reflection every time

Comment: A real type is better than a reflection/dynamic (this is what I mean). The cases are ideas, that wont work for me. But why is here `dynamic` better than `object` (keys are still unknow)?

Comment: Of course a real type would be preferable, but I imagine that the whole point of this is that you don't know what "real type" to cast the object as. So unless you parse through the object's members and determine exactly what type it is, using `dynamic` or `JObject` is your next best option. I mean, is this type defined in your program?

Comment: Some fields are "hard-coded", but most of it is dynamic (which depends current user-context).

Comment: I mean, if the JSON object is a serialized form of type `X`, does `X` exist in your program or not?

Comment: Does not exist.

Comment: Solved with a workaround (not longer working with json).